# How to get each Elasticsearch SearchRequestBuilder object from MultiSearchRequestBuilder object?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want to get each **SearchRequestBuilder** object from **MultiSearchRequestBuilder** object in the ElasticSearch java API. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you need that but at max you can get the List of **SearchRequest** from the **MultiSearchRequest** of the **MultiSearchRequestBuilder** which should be fine IMHO.

The following LOC will return the List of SearchRequests:

```
List<SearchRequest> requests = builder.request().requests();
```

where builder is the MultiSearchRequestBuilder.

**source:**  [Elastic github repo](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/action/search/MultiSearchRequest.java)

**javadoc:** [MultiSearchRequest](https://static.javadoc.io/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/6.0.1/org/elasticsearch/action/search/MultiSearchRequest.html#requests--)